# ASP.Net serialization error, using InProc session state

Tags: asp.net, session, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a particular web part to my SharePoint site, and I get the error

> "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type '[MyType]'
>   in Assembly '[MyAssembly]' is not marked as serializable."

I understand that there are generally two fixes for this: either mark the object as serializable or change the web application's session state to `"InProc"` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).  My object has member references to COM objects and so can't be made serializable, so I want to change the session state mode to InProc.  The web.config file for the site specifies this, and it's not overridden by the machine.config.

Is there any other cause for this error?  Is it possible for SharePoint to use another storage mode despite what my web.config file indicates?  Is there a way to definitively determine what storage mode an ASP.Net site is using?

The full stack trace is:

```
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)    
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)    
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()    
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)    
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)    
 at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer
```

)

Comment: I think that the message says you to add the `[Serializable]` to that class

Comment: The class in question can't be made serializable

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the "usual fix" is to set the session state to "InProc". Has this necessary got *anything* to do with session state? As Aristos pointed out, and as the error message clearly states, `MyType` in assembly `MyAssembly` is not marked as serializable... so mark it!

Comment: I guess "usual fix" isn't quite right, but as I understand it there are only 2 options: 1) change the session state mode to one that doesn't require serialization or 2) only put serializable objects in the session (i.e. mark MyType as serializable).  I could mark my class as serializable but it has non-serializable members (reference to COM objects) so it will just fail differently.

Comment: You could mark those non-serializable members with the `[NonSerialized]` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)

Comment: If they are marked NonSerialized, they won't be present when the session data is deserialized, right?  If I didn't need them, they wouldn't be members.

Comment: Yes, that's how serializable things work, they must be reconstructable . If you have COM references, you have to be able to restore them when the object is deserialized. I typically do it by implementing things using "smart" propety getters.

Comment: So can we stipulate that the class in question can't be made serializable, and just focus on getting SP/ASP.Net to not attempt to serialize it?

Comment: Well, presumably you're doing something that attempts to put an instance of `MyType` into the session state? If it can't be serialized, it can't go into session state, so... don't put it into session state.

Comment: SessionState is set to InProc, in which case this is legal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx .  What I don't know is why is it still trying to serialize my session state?

Comment: I've updated the question in light of these comments, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Is it possible that it's actually the ViewState it's trying to serialize? Not the session?

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion.  I'm pretty sure there's nothing more than strings/ints/bools in the ViewState, but I'll double-check.